# Replace NaN's in NumPy array with closest non-NaN value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a NumPy array `a` like the following:

```
>>> str(a)
'[        nan         nan         nan  1.44955726  1.44628034  1.44409573\n  1.4408188   1.43657094  1.43171624  1.42649744  1.42200684  1.42117704\n  1.42040255  1.41922908         nan         nan         nan         nan\n         nan         nan]'
```

I want to replace each NaN with the closest non-NaN value, so that all of the NaN's at the beginning get set to `1.449...` and all of the NaN's at the end get set to `1.419...`.

I can see how to do this for specific cases like this, but I need to be able to do it generally for any length of array, with any length of NaN's at the beginning and end of the array (there will be no NaN's in the middle of the numbers). Any ideas?

I can find the NaN's easily enough with `np.isnan()`, but I can't work out how to get the closest value to each NaN.

Comment: N.B. This doesn’t have to do with numpy or NaNs *per se*; it’s just about list processing in general.

Comment: @JoshLee - True, but using general list processing techniques on numpy arrays is very inefficient.  Iterating thorough each item of a numpy array in python is much slower than iterating through each item of a list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I want to replace each NaN with the closest non-NaN value... there will be no NaN's in the middle of the numbers

The following will do it:

```
ind = np.where(~np.isnan(a))[0]
first, last = ind[0], ind[-1]
a[:first] = a[first]
a[last + 1:] = a[last]
```

This is a straight `numpy` solution requiring no Python loops, no recursion, no list comprehensions etc.

Comment: In case others also have this thought... yes this is safe for arrays with no NaN's, because `a[:first]` will refer to an empty slice since `first` will be 0, and `a[last + 1:]` will refer to an empty slice since `last+1` will be after the last index.  Assignment to an empty slice has no effect. To keep the code from running unnecessarily, one could simply use `if np.any(np.isnan(a)):`

Comment: ind = np.where(a==a)[0] is another way to find the index because nan!=nan

Comment: Does this hold when the NaNs are in the middle?

Comment: @YonatanSimson no it doesn't, it fails dramatically, not sure why the accepted solution

Answer (score 64):

As an alternate solution (this will linearly interpolate for arrays `NaN`s in the middle, as well):

```
import numpy as np

# Generate data...
data = np.random.random(10)
data[:2] = np.nan
data[-1] = np.nan
data[4:6] = np.nan

print data

# Fill in NaN's...
mask = np.isnan(data)
data[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask), data[~mask])

print data
```

This yields:

```
[        nan         nan  0.31619306  0.25818765         nan         nan
  0.27410025  0.23347532  0.02418698         nan]

[ 0.31619306  0.31619306  0.31619306  0.25818765  0.26349185  0.26879605
  0.27410025  0.23347532  0.02418698  0.02418698]
```

Comment: Awesome, I had a big 2D array with a few troublesome NaNs in the middle that this smoothed out.  Thanks.

Comment: Beautiful. Best answer here.

Comment: This is useful, but it doesn't do what is in the title: : "Replace NaN's in NumPy array with closest non-NaN value".

Answer (score 5):

`NaN`s have the interesting property of comparing different from themselves, thus we can quickly find the indexes of the non-nan elements:

```
idx = np.nonzero(a==a)[0]
```

it's now easy to replace the nans with the desired value:

```
for i in range(0, idx[0]):
    a[i]=a[idx[0]]
for i in range(idx[-1]+1, a.size)
    a[i]=a[idx[-1]]
```

Finally, we can put this in a function:

```
import numpy as np

def FixNaNs(arr):
    if len(arr.shape)>1:
        raise Exception("Only 1D arrays are supported.")
    idxs=np.nonzero(arr==arr)[0]

    if len(idxs)==0:
        return None

    ret=arr

    for i in range(0, idxs[0]):
        ret[i]=ret[idxs[0]]

    for i in range(idxs[-1]+1, ret.size):
        ret[i]=ret[idxs[-1]]

    return ret
```

***edit***

Ouch, coming from C++ I always forget about list ranges... @aix's solution is way more elegant and efficient than my C++ish loops, use that instead of mine.

Comment: For what it's worth, `idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(a))` is equivalent, and much more readable, i.m.o.

Comment: @JoeKington: for anyone who works with NaNs comparing an item against itself is quite idiomatic, although I agree that your solution is clearer.

Comment: True!  `a == a` is also more efficient than `~np.isnan(a)` (direct comparison instead of inverting the opposite), which is another reason to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution!

```
def replace_leading_NaN(a, offset=0):
    if a[offset].isNaN():
        new_value = replace_leading_NaN(a, offset + 1)
        a[offset] = new_value
        return new_value
    else:
        return a[offset]

def replace_trailing_NaN(a, offset=-1):
    if a[offset].isNaN():
        new_value = replace_trailing_NaN(a, offset - 1)
        a[offset] = new_value
        return new_value
    else:
        return a[offset]
```

Comment: Thanks! The code didn't work immediately as written, but the structure was fine. I modified it to work with NumPy arrays by changing `if a[offset].isNaN()` to `if np.isnan(a[offset]):` as `ndarray` objects don't have an `isNaN` method.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the problem and had to find a custom solution for scattered NaNs. The function below replaces any NaN by the first number occurrence to the right, if none exists, it replaces it by the first number occurrence to the left. Further manipulation can be done to replace it with the mean of boundary occurrences.

```
import numpy as np

Data = np.array([np.nan,1.3,np.nan,1.4,np.nan,np.nan])

nansIndx = np.where(np.isnan(Data))[0]
isanIndx = np.where(~np.isnan(Data))[0]
for nan in nansIndx:
    replacementCandidates = np.where(isanIndx>nan)[0]
    if replacementCandidates.size != 0:
        replacement = Data[isanIndx[replacementCandidates[0]]]
    else:
        replacement = Data[isanIndx[np.where(isanIndx<nan)[0][-1]]]
    Data[nan] = replacement
```

Result is:

```
>>> Data
array([ 1.3,  1.3,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4,  1.4])
```

Comment: For large datasets, this worked well when converted to a Numba function.  Exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this

```
i = [i for i in range(len(a)) if not np.isnan(a[i])]
a = [a[i[0]] if x < i[0] else (a[i[-1]] if x > i[-1] else a[x]) for x in range(len(a))]
```

It's a bit clunky though given it's split up in two lines with nested inline if's in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using simple python iterators. They are actually more efficient here than `numpy.where`, especially with big arrays! See comparison of similar code [here](https://gist.github.com/davidak/0f82496334ebce25df4f59ab346f54a1).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, 1.44955726, 1.44628034, 1.44409573, 1.4408188, 1.43657094, 1.43171624,  1.42649744, 1.42200684, 1.42117704, 1.42040255, 1.41922908, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN, np.NAN])

mask = np.isfinite(a)

# get first value in list
for i in range(len(mask)):
    if mask[i]:
        first = i
        break

# get last vaue in list
for i in range(len(mask)-1, -1, -1):
    if mask[i]:
        last = i
        break

# fill NaN with near known value on the edges
a = np.copy(a)
a[:first] = a[first]
a[last + 1:] = a[last]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1.44955726 1.44955726 1.44955726 1.44955726 1.44628034 1.44409573
 1.4408188  1.43657094 1.43171624 1.42649744 1.42200684 1.42117704
 1.42040255 1.41922908 1.41922908 1.41922908 1.41922908 1.41922908
 1.41922908 1.41922908]
```

It replaces only the first and last NaNs like requested here.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimal, but I found out that converting to pandas Series then using [interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with "method='nearest'" was the simplest to me. However, it is necessary to make sure the edges are non-NaN.

```
data[[0,-1]] = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(mapping_read_qual))[[0,-1]]
data = pd.Series(data).interpolate(method='nearest').values
```