# invert edge values in python boolean list

Tags: python

I have a list of booleans like

```
l = [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
```

and want to invert every edge value that is `False` like

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

What is the most pythonic way to achieve that?

Comment: Those are not valid lists, also by edge value, do you mean the first and last list items?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It can't just be "the first and last list items", since the second-to-last False is also being inverted. Perhaps something along the lines of "whichever False values are covered by a flood fill starting from the first and last elements"

Comment: sorry, it is the printed list. with edge values, i mean every FALSE on the edge. when the first 5 items are FALSE and the 6. True, convert the first 5.

Comment: What do you mean by "edge value"? the first and last? or [signal edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_edge)?

Comment: **every** FALSE on the edges of the list. not only the first and last. it's quiet hard to explain, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly there's some clever one-line solution for this, but until someone comes up with it, here's a way to do it with old fashioned iteration:

```
seq = [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]

for i in range(len(seq)):
    if seq[i]:
        break
    seq[i] = True

for i in range(len(seq)-1, -1, -1):
    if seq[i]:
        break
    seq[i] = True

print(seq)
```

Result:

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Comment: This is not only the simplest solution, but also the most efficient. And the difference in performance get bigger with bigger lists. It also don't need additional dependencies like numpy. Definitely the best solution. Thanks!

See performance comparison: https://gist.github.com/davidak/0f82496334ebce25df4f59ab346f54a1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of generator expressions and then NumPy for vectorised slicing.

The idea is to calculate the first index from the beginning and end of the list separately where a value is `True`. Then use efficient NumPy slicing to update the relevant elements.

```
L = [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]

idx1 = next(i for i, j in enumerate(L) if j)
idx2 = next(i for i, j in enumerate(L[::-1]) if j)

print(idx1, idx2)  # 3 2

import numpy as np

A = np.array(L)
A[:idx1] = True
A[len(A)-idx2:] = True

print(A)

array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
        True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following simple code:

```
myList = [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]

tempList = myList[:]

# Iterate from the beginning (and invert) until the element differs from the first one
for i,v in enumerate(tempList):
    if v == tempList[0]: myList[i] = not v
    else:                break

# Iterate from the end (and invert) until the element differs from the last one
for i,v in reversed(list(enumerate(tempList))):
    if v == tempList[-1]: myList[i] = not v
    else:                 break

print(myList)
# [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Comment: this code works only once since it alternates the original list. use `myList = copy.deepcopy(myList)` to prevent that. also, the code style is not very pythonic, see http://pep8.org/ if you want to improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic of the other answers, here is a solution using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np

l = [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]

l = np.array(l)
ind = np.where(l)[0]
first, last = ind[0], ind[-1]

l[:first] = True
l[last + 1:] = True

print(l)
```

This was inspired by the answer from [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537766/2611995.