# Fill nan with nearest neighbor in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I got this 2D numpy array with missing values. Is there a simple (and reasonably fast) way of filling the nan values with the closest (preferably euclidean distance, but manhattan is ok too) non-nan value? I couldn't find such a function in numpy or scipy…

Comment: Not that this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537543/replace-nans-in-numpy-array-with-closest-non-nan-value, that question's title is just misleading

Comment: would filling the point with the average of the surrounding pixels be sufficient?

Comment: And if there are multiple different values the same distance away?

Comment: @Conic the surrounding pixels may be NaN too. But for my application, mean would be alright too

Comment: @Scott Hunter then any of these is fine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator).

E.g.:

```
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
data = ... # shape (w, h)
mask = np.where(~np.isnan(data))
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(np.transpose(mask), data[mask])
filled_data = interp(*np.indices(data.shape))
```

Showing it in action (with black as the mask here, `image_defect` is from  [from here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_inpaint.html)):

```
data = image_defect
mask = np.where(~(data == 0))
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(np.transpose(mask), data[mask])
image_result = interp(*np.indices(data.shape))
```

Then, using the plotting code from scipy:
[image]